# CSS - How does the browser know how to keep in sync the columns of two tables when implementing a fixed header table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

recently I came across this nice pen made by Nikhil Krishnan:

https://codepen.io/nikhil8krishnan/pen/WvYPvv/

As you can see, the fixed header table is implemented with a nice CSS style and almos no JS involved:

```
// '.tbl-content' consumed little space for vertical scrollbar, scrollbar width depend on browser/os/platfrom. Here calculate the scollbar width .
$(window).on("load resize ", function() {
  var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
  $('.tbl-header').css({'padding-right':scrollWidth});
}).resize();
```

This JS only adds a right padding to the table header container which is equal to the width of the vertical scroll of the body of the table.

As two HTML tables are used (one table for the header of the table and the other for the body), I thought that the browser (I tested both with Chrome and Firefox) will treat them independently one from each other, so a JS is needed in order to keep the widths of the columns of the two tables synchronised.

It turns out that when table elements have the styles `table-layout: fixed;` and `width: 100%;`, and the tables are within the same container, their columns are somehow in sync with each other, so that even if I try to add more text to one cell of a table (below a screenshot):

[image]

The text wraps as needed and doesn't expand the width of the column of the body table which is always in sync with the width of the 'COMPANY' cell.
Even if I add a `white-space: nowrap;` to the cell with extra text, you see that the cell's width remains 'synced' with the width of the heading cell 'COMPANY':

[image]

Is there a specific reason or specification that can describe this behaviour? It works in Chrome and Firefox, I didn't tested in other browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is about "fixed" that you don't understand, but the spec is the [Fixed Table Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) algorithm.

Comment: As I understood, reading the spec you posted, with `table-layout: fixed` the width of each column if all columns have `width: auto;` is the width of the table divided by the number of columns. `Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing).`

Answer (score 1):

Since the table has `width:100%` and `table-layout:fixed` and every cell of the first row have a `width:auto` then the browser will give the same width to every column, that's why these two seperate table are sync.

With this setup the columns width do not depend on the content it's just parentWidth/columnCount

Comment: You mean `Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing)` taken from https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#fixed-table-layout (which Alohci posted in his comment)?